# Navigate with arrow in custom dropdown Angular 5?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular5

I have custom dropdown. Something like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2y57jq?file=app%2Fhello.component.html). I want to navigate in the drop-down list with arrows and select items by pressing enter or clicking on them.
Each item in the drop-down list should be hovered when you navigate through them. How i can do this? Thank you.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-multiselect-dropdown

Comment: @SharmaVikram thank you for link. But no one of the existing dropdown components do not meet the requirements of design. So I was forced to invent a bicycle

Comment: please explain more or show your existing code then i will implement

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: You should track which element is currently hovered by the mouse and store the index of it in your component. (Optional, else you'd start at first item when using keys)

Step 2: Create a listener for keyup events in your component which increases or decreases the tracked index on arrow keys. That index should of cause in the limits of the items you use: not < 0 or > length of your array. You can check which key way pressed using `event.keyCode`. The method should not be processed if the element is not in focus.

```
@HostListener('window:keyup', ['$event'])
keyEventDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
   [..]
}
```

Step 3. Remove the hover effect from your pointed item when a key is pressed and apply a style to the currently selected index. The hover effect can be removed by `document.body.style.pointerEvents = 'none';` You should set that effect back to `auto` if the mouse moves. For that you could use another listener for the event mousemove.

Step 4. In your key event check if return was pressed and set the current selected index as result value.

This is a way you could go.